# Trouble getting LME in R to work with within-groups (repeated Measures) data

Tags: r, lme4-nlme

I’m having trouble figuring out how to apply the LME function to a set of data. What I have is a list of Stores and their respected customer count, by week, with various external factors for each store: Crime Rate per 100k people, % of people with a college Degree, Level of inequality, and so forth (sample Below.)

```
Store   Week    CustomerCount   CrimeRate   %collegeDegree  Inequality  Median Income
1       1         200              5        0.25            0.4         25000
1       2         259               5       0.25            0.4         25000
1       3         234              5        0.25            0.44        25000
…                       
5       1         106               1       0.2         0.43            26000
5       2         96                1       0.2         0.42            26000
5       3         101               2       0.21        0.42            26000
```

Now, what I’m trying to do is this: I’m trying to run an **annual** regression of the data to determine if some of the external factors (crime Rate, college rate, inequality level) have an effect on store customer count.

Now, I need to do a repeated measure analysis on this where the repeated measures are Week, and entity of store has the repeated values. I’ve set up the LME function thusly:

   Lme(CustomerCount ~ CrimeRate + CollegeRate + InequalitlyLevel, random = ???? , data=the.data)

So, my question is: what do I put in for the random variable? Is it “…,random = ~1|week/Store,…” or a variation thereof?

Answer (score 0):

The problem you have is that the repeated measurements are not independent of each other, but correlated. One way to deal with this is by using random effects.

The first random effect you want to add is a random intercept:

```
lme(data= the.data, CustomerCount ~ Week + CrimeRate +  CollegeRate + InequalitlyLevel, 
               random=~1|Store)
```

With this model, you assume that all the stores have the same linear time effect, but that the repeated measurements are correlated. It might be that you have to go a step further, being that the stores each have a random time effect. If so, you would have to model:

```
lme(data= the.data, CustomerCount ~ Week + CrimeRate +  CollegeRate + InequalitlyLevel, 
               random=~Week|Store)
```

You can find out with a likelihood ratio test which model to use.